# IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

i have just started programming with python and i have write this code:

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 600
speed = [2, 2]
black = 1, 1, 1

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
player1 = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
player1rect = player1.get_rect()

mod_x = mod_y = 0

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_W
                movex = 2
            if event.key == K_S
                movex = -2

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

but if i trying to run it it just says:

```
     File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Pong\pong.py", line 22
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

and i need help to resolve this error. and if there is more fails at my pong code please write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of the `if` and `elif` don't match (you had a mix of tabs and spaces).  What you had before:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
```

This should fix your issue:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
    sys.exit()
elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
    ...
```